# Using column name in ggplot geom_jitter() function call within the dplyr format

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

Maybe there is a better approach and I'm asking an "XY problem".

I want to control the amount of jitter on my scatter plot to be a percentage of the total width of the variable in that dimension. I wrote a function scale_jitter() which computer the amount in that dimension based on the portion, p, provided. This works fine so long as I explicitly drop the df$variable in my scale_jitter() function. However, I like coding things the tidyverse/dplyr way and so although the following code works, it is calculating the range based on what is assigned to df$a and df$b in the current scope, and not calculating the range based on the dplyr::filter() function that comes before it.

```
scale_jitter <- function(x,p=0.02) {
  return((max(x)-min(x))*p)
}

df <- tibble(a=rep(rnorm(n=5,mean=50,sd=25),20),
             b=rep(rnorm(n=5,mean=50,sd=25),20))

df %>%
  filter(a < 50) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=a,y=b)) +
  geom_jitter(
    width=scale_jitter(df$a),
    height=scale_jitter(df$b)
  )
```

I'd like something like the following to work, but I get object not found errors for a and b. I've tried .$a and .$b, but that doesn't work either.

```
df %>%
  filter(a < 50) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=a,y=b)) +
  geom_jitter(
    width=scale_jitter(a),
    height=scale_jitter(b)
  )
```

Ultimately I'm after setting a portion/percent for the geom_jitter height and width parameters instead of a value that has units.

Answer (score 1):

The tricky thing here is trying to pass piped data into ggplot and then into a specific geom. According to this [blog](http://www.win-vector.com/blog/2018/10/piping-into-ggplot2/) you can use the [wrapr](https://winvector.github.io/wrapr/) package to use a modified pipe (the so-called 'dot-arrow-pipe') to pipe objects into ggplot and its subsequent geoms. Apparently the problem lies in the structure of how a ggplot is built - by adding '+' objects together where the traditional pipe "%>%" usually ties functions together.

I have modified the reprex for use with the 'dot-arrow-pipe'. Important to note with the dot-arrow-pipe "%.>%" you need to specify the "." for every data argument:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(wrapr) #install this package

scale_jitter <- function(x,p=0.02) {
  return((max(x)-min(x))*p)
}


#tell wrapr how to treat ggplot objects
apply_left.gg <- function(pipe_left_arg,
                          pipe_right_arg,
                          pipe_environment,
                          left_arg_name,
                          pipe_string,
                          right_arg_name) {
  pipe_right_arg <- eval(pipe_right_arg,
                         envir = pipe_environment,
                         enclos = pipe_environment)
  pipe_left_arg + pipe_right_arg 
}



df <- tibble(a=rep(rnorm(n=5,mean=50,sd=25),20),
             b=rep(rnorm(n=5,mean=50,sd=25),20))

#with the %.>% the '.' has to be specified in each call
df %.>%
  filter(., a < 50) %.>%
  ggplot(data = ., aes(x=a,y=b)) %.>%
  geom_jitter(
    width=scale_jitter(.$a),
    height=scale_jitter(.$b)
  )
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Not really what I was after. I was trying to avoid making temporary variables to hold the jitter values.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. That is an interesting question - sending a pipe from the main ggplot call into a geom. I have updated my answer with a possible solution.